# What notifications are available for iCloud?

Tags: ios, icloud, nsnotifications

I'd like to see what iCloud is doing behind the scenes to help understand it and program it better. Looking at the documentation, I can only find these two notifications:

```
NSUbiquitousKeyValueStoreDidChangeExternallyNotification
NSPersistentStoreDidImportUbiquitousContentChangesNotification
```

Are there other notifications available? It seems like a very short list. Can someone give me a more complete list of iCloud notifications to observe?

Answer (score 1):

If there aren't any more in the documentation then there aren't any more. And even if there where you shouldn't use them, using undocumented stuff is a bad idea.

If you still insist you could register an observer for a notification using `nil` as the notification name. That way you'll get all notifications no matter what they are called.